# Cache on Varnish 4+ based on Cache Control header and not cookies

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I want to cache on varnish solely based on cache control header. If public or max-age is mentioned, then page should be cached irrespective of cookie, In case of no-store or no-cache cache should bypass and proper session connection should be made with cookie. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
sub vcl_recv {
 if ( req.http.X-Force-Cache )
{
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.Cache-Control;
unset req.http.pragma;
unset req.http.ttl;
}
      if (req.http.Authorization ) {
           /* Not cacheable by default */
           return (pass);
      }

if (req.method == "POST" ) {
       #set req.hash_always_miss = true;
           return (pass);
    }

}

sub vcl_hash {

if ( req.http.X-Force-Cache )
{
hash_data(req.http.X-Force-Cache);
}
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
if ( (beresp.http.Cache-control ~ "(no-cache|no-store)"))
{
    #unset bereq.http.Cookie;
    #unset beresp.http.Set-cookie;
    unset bereq.http.X-Force-Cache;
}
elseif ( ( bereq.http.X-Force-Cache  ) )
{
 unset beresp.http.Set-cookie;
    unset bereq.http.cookie;
    unset beresp.http.cookie;
#    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    unset bereq.http.X-Force-Cache;
     set beresp.ttl = 7d;
    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
}
else
{
    unset beresp.http.Set-cookie;
    unset bereq.http.cookie;
    unset beresp.http.cookie;
#    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    set bereq.http.X-Force-Cache = "1";
     set beresp.ttl = 7d;
    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
 }

}


sub vcl_deliver {
    if ( req.http.X-Force-Cache )
    {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    unset resp.http.Cookie;
    unset resp.http.Set-cookie;
    return(restart);
    }
     if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
 
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    set resp.http.Mobile = req.http.CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer;
    set resp.http.X-Device = req.http.X-Device;
    set resp.http.X-Force-Cache = req.http.X-Force-Cache;

   
}
```

I also would like to hide cache control header from user in case its cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Storing objects in the cache

This should do the trick when it comes to respecting the `Cache-Control` header and disregarding the `Set-Cookie` header.

```
sub vcl_backend response {
   if(beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private|no-cache|no-store" || beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
      set beresp.ttl = 120s
   }
   return (deliver);
}
```

This code will store objects in cache that have a `Set-Cookie` header unless a `no-cache`, `no-store`, `max-age=0` or `s-maxage=0` appears in the `Cache-Control` header.

It only differs slightly from [the Varnish built-in VCL behavior for `vcl_backend_response`](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#11-vcl_backend_response).

However, the `Set-Cookie` header will also be stored in the cache when that happens, which seems dangerous.

Maybe you'd want to strip off the `Set-Cookie` header then. Here's the code to conditionally remove `Set-Cookie` headers:

```
sub vcl_backend response {
   if(beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private|no-cache|no-store" || beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
      set beresp.ttl = 120s
   } else {
      unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie
   }
   return (deliver);
}
```

### Serving objects from the cache

We also need to define the caching behavior of incoming requests that have a `Cookie` request header.

Here's the code I'd use for that:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PRI") {
        /* This will never happen in properly formed traffic (see: RFC7540) */
        return (synth(405));
    }
    if (!req.http.host &&
      req.esi_level == 0 &&
      req.proto ~ "^(?i)HTTP/1.1") {
        /* In HTTP/1.1, Host is required. */
        return (synth(400));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "DELETE" &&
      req.method != "PATCH") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.http.Authorization) {
        return (pass);
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

The only way this differs from [the Varnish built-in VCL for `vcl_recv`](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#1-vcl_recv) is the fact that the `req.http.Cookie` check is removed.

There's a lot of extra code there to prevent caching from taking place for uncacheable request methods or in case an `Authorization` header is sent.

However, if you don't care about any of that, you could just as well use the following code:

```
sub vcl_recv { 
    if (req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD") {   
        return(hash);
    }
}
```

This will serve everything from cache for cacheable request methods and uses built-in VCL behavior for all other cases. With the measures in place in `vcl_backend_response` the `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` header will ensure uncacheable responses never end up in the cache.

### Varnish's built-in VCL behavior

It's important to understand that Varnish has a built-in VCL behavior. Here's a tutorial about the various aspects of this behavior: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl.

VCL should only extend the behavior in situations where it has a detrimental effect on the hit rate or the flexibility of your application.

Please have a look at the tutorial to understand the impact of the VCL code I'm suggesting.

### All-in-one VCL code:

Here's the all-in-one VCL code you can use to get the job done. You might want to tweak it a bit:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv { 
    if (req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD") {   
        return(hash);
    }
}
sub vcl_backend response {
   if(beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private|no-cache|no-store" || beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
      set beresp.ttl = 120s
   } else {
      unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie
   }
   return (deliver);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked like a charm. beresp.uncacheable = true saved my day

Comment: `set beresp.uncacheable=true;` ensures that requests for this resource bypass the request coalescing waitlist. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9G9ipVQCZ9w for more info about request coalescing.